# sysdate range to whole value

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Is it possible to turn the current time stamp to a whole number?
Example: If `sysdate` returns **1/19/2022 5:36:49 PM** can I turn that to **1/19/2022 5PM** since it falls in the 5PM range.

Here is my query

```
    Select FACILITY, TRK_ID,  LOT_DTTM, IN_QTY
from TRK_ID_LOT
WHERE facility in 'DP1DM5'
and trk_id like ('AE%')
and lot_dttm > sysdate - 1
```

EXAMPLE:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate it to *hours*:

```
SQL> select trunc(to_date('1/19/2022 5:36:49 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss pm'), 'hh') res
  2  from dual;

RES
----------------------
01/19/2022 05:00:00 PM

SQL>
```

---

If you want to update rows, do so using the same function:

```
update your_table set
  date_column = trunc(date_column, 'hh');
```

Comment: I updated the question. I am trying to change all the time records. Instead of showing the current time I want the current time to be changed to the current hour.

Comment: So update it; nothing changes, you'd still truncate that date value to hours. See edited answer.

Comment: I can't make edits to the table itself. I only have read access. Sorry I am new to SQL

Comment: What do you really want? You said you want to "change" - that's "update". Now you said that you can't do any updates. So what do you want? If it is just a select, then use the same TRUNC as suggested: `select col1, col1, TRUNC(date_column, 'hh') date column from ...`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it! Here is the completed code `Select FACILITY, TRK_ID,  IN_QTY, TRUNC(LOT_DTTM, 'hh') 
from TRK_ID_LOT
WHERE facility in 'DP1DM5'
and trk_id like ('AE%')
and lot_dttm > sysdate - 1`